# Dataweave : Is it possible to execute a string as code?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Assuming there is a **property** in a *file.properties* like : `aaa.code=now() - |P2D|`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ "from": p('aaa.code') }
```

The property arrives as a string and is not interpreted. How / is it possible to interpret the code in Dataweave 2 ? I found eval or execute but both are experimental and it does not fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use read function to get the desired result:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-read

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(p('aaa.code'))
```

Comment: Splendid ! Thank a lots !

Comment: It is probably a bad idea to use read() without specifying an output format. The default in such cases is `application/dw` which is meant only for debugging and should never be used in production applications.